# NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a huge problem with NSFetchedResultsCOntroller. I'm using fetchedResultsContrioller and I have interface with 3 tabs. They use Core Data too. But I have a problem with only ONE of them.

```
Faktura *faktura = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = faktura.NumerFV; // THE CRASH IS HERE

int productsCount = [faktura.Produkty count]; // OR HERE
NSString *kontrahentName = [faktura.Kontrahent valueForKey:@"NazwaKrotka"]; // OR HERE

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nabywca: %@, produktów: %d",kontrahentName, productsCount];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"faktura_cell_image.png"];
cell.hidesImageWhileEditing = YES;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

`Faktura` is my NSManagedObject subclass.

NSZombie says:
`-[CFDictionary retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d619d0`

My fetchedResultsController implementation:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) return __fetchedResultsController;

// Setup the table

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Faktura" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Setup the sort descriptors

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DataWystawienia" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Create the fetched results controller

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) { // THE CRASH IS HERE UNLESS I INIT NSFetchedResultsController WITH cacheName:nil. (IF IT'LL BE cacheName:@"Root" IT CRASHES.)

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Błąd Krytyczny" message:@"Wystąpił nieznany błąd przy zmienianiu zawartości w bazie danych. Dla dobra twoich danych prosimy niezwłocznie wyjść z aplikacji i spróbować ponownie." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**Faktura.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface NSArrayToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer @end
@interface NSDictionaryToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer @end

@interface Faktura : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * DataZaplaty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * NumerFV;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * DataWystawienia;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * DataSprzedazy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id Produkty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id Kontrahent;

@end
```

**Faktura.m**

```
#import "Faktura.h"

@implementation Faktura

@dynamic DataZaplaty;
@dynamic NumerFV;
@dynamic DataWystawienia;
@dynamic DataSprzedazy;
@dynamic Produkty;
@dynamic Kontrahent;

+ (void)initialize {
if (self == [Faktura class] ) {
    NSArrayToDataTransformer *arrayTransformer = [[NSArrayToDataTransformer alloc] init];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:arrayTransformer forName:@"NSArrayToDataTransformer"];
    NSDictionaryToDataTransformer *dictTransformer = [[NSDictionaryToDataTransformer alloc] init];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:dictTransformer forName:@"NSDictionaryToDataTransformer"];
}
}

@end


@implementation NSArrayToDataTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
return [NSData class];
}


- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
return data;
}


- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
return [array autorelease];
}

@end


@implementation NSDictionaryToDataTransformer

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
return [NSData class];
}


- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
return data;
}


- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
return [dict autorelease];
}

@end
```

**My `Faktura` object insertion code**

```
- (void)fakturaCreator:(FakturaCreator *)form didEndWithValues:(NSDictionary *)values {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    Faktura *newFaktura = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newFaktura setNumerFV:[values valueForKey:@"id"]];
    [newFaktura setDataWystawienia:[values valueForKey:@"creationDate"]];
    [newFaktura setDataSprzedazy:[values valueForKey:@"sellDate"]];
    [newFaktura setDataZaplaty:[values valueForKey:@"paymentDate"]];
    [newFaktura setKontrahent:[values valueForKey:@"kontrahent"]];
    [newFaktura setProdukty:[values valueForKey:@"produkty"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.emptySectionView setHidden:YES];
}
```

*`FakturaCreator` is my UIViewController where user create an invoice. values array contains dictionary of values: my invoice number (`NSString`), various dates (`NSDate`), client (`NSDictionary`) and products (`NSArray`).*

Please help me!
If you want some additional code, i'll put it here.

**EDIT:** It is **definetly** `objectAtIndexPath:` fault. When I comment all the cell setup code (it will display empty cell) and then try to remove the cell, app crashes on line which contains `objectatIndexPath:`.

**EDIT #2:** Anybody? Please, help me... :(

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `fetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Do you use `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController * fetchedResultsController;` in your header file? Or is it `assign`?

Comment: Then that part looks fine... The next suspect would be your `Faktura` class. Would you mind post its .h & .m file up?

Comment: Posted. I use it for my transformable values conversion.

Comment: I think that this is **not** the `Faktura`'s fault. When I use `NSManagedObject *faktura = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` instead of `Faktura *faktura = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];`, the result is the same

Comment: What happens if you insert NSLog(cell.textLabel.text) before crashing line? I'm wondering if it's possible that cell or cell.textLabel is the culprit here, since fetchedResultsController and Fakture seem good.

Comment: How about implementing Faktura -dealloc and placing either NSLog() or breakpoint there? Then you might be able to track down where the deallocation is taking place.

Comment: Ok, I put `NSLog(@"deallocated")` in `dealloc` and additionaly breakpointed that. _No result...._ And this is why my probles is **very** strange...

Comment: Which of the Faktura attributes are transformed?

Comment: Kontrahent and Produkty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the problem. In your `NSArrayToDataTransformer`, you have this:

```
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
    return [array autorelease];
}
```

Since `unarchiveObjectWithData:` does not begin with "alloc", "new", "copy", or "mutableCopy", you do not own the object and therefore may not autorelease it. You have the same problem in your `NSDictionaryToDataTransformer`.

Comment: Yeah!!! I forgot about the fact that I can't release objects that i don't own. And now it's working! Thank you, thank you thank you! :) _I'll give you +50 after 19h :/_

Answer (score 1):

Your inclusion of the value transformers into the class and the using `+initialize` is non-standard. Although `+initialize` should work, it is recommended in the Core Data docs not use any kind of initialization methods at all but to rely on `awakeFromFetch` for initialization.

I would check your tableview methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection:` to ensure you are getting the right indexes back from the tableview. If the rows in the tableview and the count of the `fetchedObjects` array come out of sync, you can get this kind of crash.

Comment: And there's a problem, because fetchedResultsController returns the real number of rows. NSManagedObject crashes my app. I'll check awakeFromFetch method and write the result.

Comment: Nope... Same result. I'll post my Faktura object insertion code. Maybe there's a problem.